# mysql (5.1) command line interface and my madness

Tags: mysql, command-line

Got two little problems with this interface. The worse one is that I have a file with a blank line (i have removed the SQL to demonstrate!). Tried to use mysql but get this

```
C:\Users\edheal\Desktop>mysql -e "blank.sql" -h localhost -u test -p
Enter password: *
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
nual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear 'blank.sql' at line 1
C:\Users\edheal\Desktop>cat -v "blank.sql"
^M

C:\Users\edheal\Desktop>
```

What could possibly be the problem? It is just a blank line!

The second - just me being lazy during development. Is it possible to not have a password on the account? Seems that the minimum is one character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
mysql -h localhost -u test -pYourPasword < "blank.sql"
```

One some standard installations, the root user does not have any password. But it is not possible to set an existing password to "empty".

Answer (score 2):

A blank line is not a valid SQL statement therefore it's a syntax error.

Comment: @Ed Heal: why would you run mysql without a statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Just made the problem as simple as possible

Comment: @Ed Heal: well you created a new problem with that. What is your **real** problem?

Comment: All - thank you for you help. My predicesor has put a wrapper around `mysql` or another machine to remove blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

The `-e` or the `--execute` option expects you to have the SQL command following it:

```
mysql -e "select ....." -h localhost -u test -p
```

If you want to execute the commands listed in a file say `test.sql` you can do:

```
mysql -h localhost -u test -p < test.sql
```